# I have been trying to display histogram on google colab but it is not showing

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to display histogram on google colab but it is not showing. Below is the code that is **not** displaying:

```
//imports
from chart_studio import plotly
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go

// code starts from here
trace = go.Histogram( 
x = data.defects,
opacity = 0.75,
name = "Defects",
marker = dict(color = 'green'))

hist_data = [trace]
hist_layout = go.Layout(barmode='overlay',
title = 'Defects',
xaxis = dict(title = 'True - False'),
yaxis = dict(title = 'Frequency'),
)
fig = go.Figure(data = hist_data, layout = hist_layout)
iplot(fig) //This is not displaying anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```